# org-mode occur-tree multiple tags

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I am trying to add an agenda custom command that shows me a sparse tree of items contain either `NEXT` or `TODO` using `occur-tree`.

When I run `M-x org-occur RET NEXT\|TODO` manually, it works fine.  However, when I try to add it as an agenda command as following

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(("n" occur-tree "NEXT\|TODO")))
```

it doesn't match anything. I tried several combinations such as `"NEXT|TODO"`, `"NEXT\\|TODO"`, `"\(NEXT\|TODO\)"` etc. and none of them worked.

Comment: The occur sparse tree works for the **current** file. Do you have the file in question open when you run this custom agenda?

Comment: Please describe "works fine" and "make it work". Just what is the behavior you see that you don't like, and what behavior are you looking for?

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, happening on the current file.

Comment: @Drew, I edited my question to clarify.